# docker-compose not mounting content of a volume to the container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-container

I have a simple `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"

services:
  my-service:
    build:
      context: ./services/my-service
    volumes:
      - ./shared/models:/app/shared/models
```

My `./shared/models` folder is a shared NodeJS lib that I want to mount over to my container. However, the contents of the folder are not mounted, apart from the `node_modules`.

```
root@container # ls ../../shared/models 
node_modules
```

What seems to be the issue?

**EDIT**

```
FROM ****/******:latest

USER node

# Set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /sdwan/domains/sd-wan
WORKDIR /sdwan/domains/sd-wan

# Copy all dependencies
COPY --chown=node:node package.json .
COPY --chown=node:node package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "serverless", "offline" ]
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], including enough of the Dockerfile to demonstrate the problem?  If the `models` directory is a library your application is using, why not `COPY` it into your image so that it can be self-contained?

Comment: hey @DavidMaze just edited the post and added the Dockerfile ... the reason why I'm not using COPY is that the shared lib is outside of the folder where I am referencing the Dockerfile. in my package.json, I have a dependency "@namespace/myservice-models": "file:../../shared/models", which I use, and it gets added to the node_modules of the primary project... I am just replicating that, so the shared lib is mounted (available) to the container, so the container can install all dependencies necessary when running npm install. There is a workaround, by pushing the lib to NPM, but don't want that